# How to send notification about the change of composite collection

Tags: wpf, notifications, compositecollection

I've got a composite collection. After modifications on its items from code behind I want the View to get updated. But I don't know how to notify the view. I tried the `INotifyCollectionChanged`, but it didn't work for me.

```
    protected ObservableCollection<ScriptParameterComboItem> cItems

    public virtual CompositeCollection CItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new CompositeCollection {new CollectionContainer {Collection = cItems}};
        }
    }

    public void ConvertValue(params object[] parameters)
    {
        string newAverageOption = DisplayValueConverter.Convert(1, parameters);
        var enumItem = cItems[1];
        enumItem.Value = newAverageOption;
        RaiseCollectionChanged("CItems");
    }


    protected void RaiseCollectionChanged(string property)
    {
        if(CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ScriptParameterComboItem` class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. So when **changing** it's properties, listeners will be notified. Using `ObservableCollection` helps listeners to be notified when something is **added** to the collection or **removed** from. Not changing the actual data within every single item.